# Subtract 2 strings result decimal

Tags: javascript, string, math, decimal

I have 2 fields that have a string value, and I would like to have the result of subtraction a decimal number.

Those 2 fields might have following value: 2.43 and 1.13;

I know I could split the strings then do the math and then concatenate the result but I am thinking that if there isn't an easier option. I don't know why `parseFloat()` wouldn't work. It might be because instead of 2.43 I have 2,43 ( romanian decimal "style" ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can first use a regex sentence to change ' for .

Here, str is your field value.

```
var res = str.replace(",", ".");
```

And then you can do ParseFloat(res).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` on the string to change the comma to a decimal point, and then use `parseFloat`.

```
var a = '2,43';
var b = '1,13';

var a = parseFloat(a.replace(',', '.'));
var b = parseFloat(b.replace(',', '.'));

console.log(a - b); // 1.3000000000000003
console.log((a - b).toFixed(2)) // 1.30
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuo07exn/)